# targeting child html element using css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Following html structure is rendered

```
<div id="details">
    <div class="col-lg-12 header-section" style="">
</div>
```

I'm trying to apply css using this css selector

```
div#details > .col-lg-12+.header-section {
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
}
```

but this doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `+`

```css
div#details > .col-lg-12.header-section {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="details">
    <div class="col-lg-12 header-section" style="">DIV</div>
</div>
```

With your css code you are selecting element with class `header-section` that is next-sibling of `col-lg-12` so it would work in this case [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/557/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent .child {
    /** Your css here **/
}
```

Very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the '+'! It would work right after you do that

```css
#details > .col-lg-12.header-section {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="details">
    <div class="col-lg-12 header-section">This is a div i guess LOL</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
div#details > .col-lg-12.header-section
```

Also, the div before #details is not necessary since you should only have one element with that id anyway, so you might think about removing that.

Here is the fiddle with background-colors instead of margin on selected item just to make the effect more visible: https://jsfiddle.net/j30hq8jt/11/